# Resolve union structure in Rust FFI

Tags: rust, unions, xlib, ffi

I have problem with resolving c-union structure XEvent.

I'm experimenting with Xlib and X Record Extension in Rust. I'm generate ffi-bindings with [rust-bindgen](https://github.com/crabtw/rust-bindgen). All code hosted on github [alxkolm/rust-xlib-record](https://github.com/alxkolm/rust-xlib-record).

Trouble happen on line [src/main.rs:106](https://github.com/alxkolm/rust-xlib-record/blob/master/src/main.rs#L106) when I try extract data from XEvent structure.

```
let key_event: *mut xlib::XKeyEvent = event.xkey();
println!("KeyPress {}", (*key_event).keycode); // this always print 128 on any key
```

My program listen key events and print out `keycode`. But it is always 128 on any key I press. I think this wrong conversion from C union type to Rust type.

Definition of XEvent starts here [src/xlib.rs:1143](https://github.com/alxkolm/rust-xlib-record/blob/master/src/xlib.rs#L1143). It's the c-union. Original C definition [here](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/structures.html).

Code from GitHub can be run by `cargo run` command. It's compile without errors.

What I do wrong?

Comment: Could you specify exactly the error you encounter? If you have a compilation-time error, then the compiler error message would be useful; if you have a load time error, then the... Or is the problem that you always get `128` and were expecting something else?

Comment: On any key I press keycode always is 128. It's fully compilable without errors. Fix text of question.

Comment: Have you checked that the type of the event is what you would expect? The generated Rust code obeys you blindly: you ask for `xkey` it interprets the memory correspondingly, however if it were not a key-pressed event but something else, then it won't make sense.

Comment: Yes, you right. I wrong in memory interpret early in code. And event variable contains wrong data. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beware that `rustbindgen` generates binding to C `union` with as much safety as in C; as a result, when calling:

```
event.xkey(); // gets the C union 'xkey' field
```

There is no runtime check that `xkey` is the field currently containing a value.

This is because since C does not have tagged `union` (ie, the `union` knowing which field is currently in use), developers came up with various ways of encoding this information (*), the two that I know of being:

- an external supplier; typically another field of the structure right before the `union`
- the first field of each of the structures in the `union`

Here, you are in the latter case `int type;` is the first field of the union and each nested structure starts with `int _type;` to denote this. As a result, you need a two-steps approach:

1. consult `type()`
2. depending on the value, call the correct reinterpretation

The mapping from the value of type to the actual field being used should be part of the documentation of the C library, hopefully.

I invite you to come up with a wrapper around this low-level `union` that will make it safer to retrieve the result. At the very least, you could check it is the right type in the accessor; the full approach being to come up with a Rust `enum` that would wrap proxies to all the fields and allow pattern-matching.

(*) and actually sometimes disregard it altogether, for example in C99 to reinterpret a `float` as an `int` a `union { float f; int i; }` can be used.